# Using StringReader on HTML file: Links images in the wrong directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using ITextSharp to create a .pdf file from a html file.

**My Problem:** I get an error when I read the HTML file that contains an image. It looks for the image in the C:// directory when it should be looking in my visual studio project directory: C://users/x/documents/visualstudio2010/projects/myproject/...

Error:

> Could not find file 'C:\topBorder.jpg'

My code:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/HTMLTemplates/a.html")));
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null); // ERROR THROWN HERE
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src="topBorder.jpg" alt=""/>
```

The image I am loading sits in the same directory as the a.html file so it should load it fine shouldnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Only specifying the image name will look for it under the root folder. Try this

```
<img src="~/HTMLTemplates/topBorder.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. Is src="" a typo should it be src="? Either way it still fails with either "No permission to access C:/ drive" or "Could not find file C:/~/HTMLTemplates/topBorder.jpg"

Comment: Looks like your problem is with ITextSharp. Try this, it has a solution: http://www.draggerco.com/node/2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="~/topBorder.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: that doesn;t work either: it says "could not find file 'C:\~\topBorder.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="./HTMLTemplates/topBorder.jpg" alt=""/>
```

I tried, it works.

I hope that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, iTextSharp knows nothing about ASP.Net so as you saw using `~/Images` doesn't work. Also, like any DLL, the concept of "the current directory" isn't always what you think it is. The good news is that its pretty easy to fix.

The third parameter to the `ParseToList` command is a `Dictionary` of providers. One of the providers is the `IMG_BASEURL` provider directive which you can set to your specific folder. One thing to be careful of, if set this gets prepended to the value of the `SRC` attribute so you need to make sure this includes the trailing slash.

```
//Create a provider collection to set various processing properties
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> providers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
//Set the image base. This will be prepended to the SRC so make sure to include a trailing slash
providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL, @"C:\users\x\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\myproject\");

var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null, providers);
```